# What is an RStudio project (.Rproj)?

Tags: r, rstudio

What are technical and non-technical definitions for what an RStudio project (.Rproj) ***is***?

These sites give information about what an .Rproj is used for: 
https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200526207-Using-Projects.
https://r4ds.had.co.nz/workflow-projects.html

Answer (score 0):

It is effectively just a Debian control file.

Does this site answer your question?

https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/index.html#document-ch-controlfields

Comment: thanks @Johnny5ish. It does a little. I was needing to explain this to someone (non-technical audience) about what an R project was and didn't know how to explain the object itself and then I became more interested in the more technical definition